# Adding multiple ORDER BY clauses to an NHibernate query throws exception

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Perhaps there's something wrong with my Linq query, or I'm running into something NHibernate doesn't support.  Either way, this is a strange one.  Here's my query that *does* work:

```
// Query for all ingredients, most used ingredients first
var ingredients = (from ing in session.Query<Ingredients>()
                   orderby ((from p in session.Query<RecipeIngredients>()
                            where p.Ingredient == ing
                            select p.RecipeIngredientId).Count()) descending
                   select new IngredientSource(ing.IngredientId, ing.DisplayName));
```

This produces the query:

```
select
   ingredient0_.IngredientId as col_0_0_,
   ingredient0_.DisplayName as col_1_0_
from ingredients ingredient0_
order by (select cast(count(recipeingr1_.RecipeIngredientId) as int4) from recipeingredients recipeingr1_ where recipeingr1_.IngredientId=ingredient0_.IngredientId) desc
```

I don't really like the weird `cast()` thing going on, but I doubt that slows anything down.

However, I need to add a *second* order by as well.  The results need to be sorted by the *ingredient name* next.  So I've tried the obvious:

```
var ingredients = (from ing in session.Query<Ingredients>()
                   orderby ((from p in session.Query<RecipeIngredients>()
                            where p.Ingredient == ing
                            select p.RecipeIngredientId).Count()) descending,
                            ing.DisplayName
                   select new IngredientSource(ing.IngredientId, ing.DisplayName));
```

This throws the exception:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTreeNodeException' was thrown. [.Select[KitchenPC.DB.Models.Ingredients,KitchenPC.Context.IngredientSource](.ThenBy[KitchenPC.DB.Models.Ingredients,System.String](.OrderByDescending[KitchenPC.DB.Models.Ingredients,System.Int32](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[KitchenPC.DB.Models.Ingredients], Quote((ing, ) => (.Count[System.Guid](.Select[KitchenPC.DB.Models.RecipeIngredients,System.Guid](.Where[KitchenPC.DB.Models.RecipeIngredients](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[KitchenPC.DB.Models.RecipeIngredients], Quote((p, ) => (Equal(p.Ingredient, ing))), ), Quote((p, ) => (p.RecipeIngredientId)), ), ))), ), Quote((ing, ) => (ing.DisplayName)), ), Quote((ing, ) => (new IngredientSource(ing.IngredientId, ing.DisplayName, ))), )]
  Source=NHibernate
  QueryString=.Select[KitchenPC.DB.Models.Ingredients,KitchenPC.Context.IngredientSource](.ThenBy[KitchenPC.DB.Models.Ingredients,System.String](.OrderByDescending[KitchenPC.DB.Models.Ingredients,System.Int32](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[KitchenPC.DB.Models.Ingredients], Quote((ing, ) => (.Count[System.Guid](.Select[KitchenPC.DB.Models.RecipeIngredients,System.Guid](.Where[KitchenPC.DB.Models.RecipeIngredients](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[KitchenPC.DB.Models.RecipeIngredients], Quote((p, ) => (Equal(p.Ingredient, ing))), ), Quote((p, ) => (p.RecipeIngredientId)), ), ))), ), Quote((ing, ) => (ing.DisplayName)), ), Quote((ing, ) => (new IngredientSource(ing.IngredientId, ing.DisplayName, ))), )
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException()
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate()
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Analyze(String collectionRole)
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow)
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
       at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at KitchenPC.DB.DatabaseAdapter.LoadIngredientsForIndex() in c:\KitchenPC\DB\DatabaseAdapter.cs:line 172
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To me, this looks like an internal error of NHibernate.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Agreed.  I'm  happy to log a bug, but I'm hoping there's a work around to unblock me for now..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Is using a different querying technology like QueryOver an option?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - Yes, however I've already done so and posted it below as an answer.  The Linq version seems cleaner; I wish it would work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've translated the Linq query to an `ICriteria` (`QueryOver<>`) query, and this seems to work.  However, the code is fairly messy.  Or, awesome depending on what you're into.

```
Models.Ingredients ing = null;
int? count = null;
var popularity = QueryOver.Of<Models.RecipeIngredients>()
   .Where(p => p.Ingredient.IngredientId == ing.IngredientId)
   .ToRowCountQuery();

var ingredients = session.QueryOver<Models.Ingredients>(() => ing)
   .SelectList(list => list
      .Select(p => p.IngredientId)
      .Select(p => p.DisplayName)
      .SelectSubQuery(popularity).WithAlias(() => count)
   )
   .OrderByAlias(() => count).Desc()
   .ThenBy(p => p.DisplayName).Asc()
   .List<Object[]>()
   .Select(i => new IngredientSource((Guid)i[0], (String)i[1]));
```

This produces a very similar query to the original:

```
SELECT
   this_.IngredientId as y0_,
   this_.DisplayName as y1_,
   (SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM recipeingredients this_0_ WHERE this_0_.IngredientId = this_.IngredientId) as y2_
FROM ingredients this_
ORDER BY y2_ desc, this_.DisplayName asc
```

Comment: In my experience the LINQ provider is very buggy and about 75% of the time for even moderately complicated queries I have to switch to QueryOver anyway. I've started writing everything in QueryOver right off the bat because of problems like this one.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - Yea, I was the opposite.  I started writing everything with `QueryOver`, but recently started using `Query` more for very simply queries, especially ones where you just want a couple columns from the model.  `QueryOver` is definitely more mature, since it's built on `ICriteria`, and far more powerful.  I think both have their place, depending on the situation.  If it's a bug (which it appears to be), I'd like to log it.